# How to generate empty JSON array in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, for-json

On SQL Server, I have an request [generating a list of object in JSON format using `FOR JSON PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). But I can't manage to handle the case where no rows are returned.

##### DDL and sample data population

Create a table nammed `mytable`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable] (
    [field_a] VARCHAR (50)     NULL,
    [field_b] VARCHAR (50)     NULL,
    [id]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_mytable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);
```

Database used:
*Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8    May 12 2022 23:11:24    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation*

##### The request

```sql
SELECT
 [mytable].[field_a] as [a],
 [mytable].[field_b] as [b]
FROM
 [mytable]
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

##### Expectation when no rows are returned

When rows are returned the request should return the following structure:

```json
[]
```

##### Reality when no rows are returned

The request as it's written **return an empty result** instead:

##### An ugly solution

I have seen the `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` option that I combined with CONCAT:

```sql
SELECT
 CONCAT(
  '[',
  (
   SELECT
    [mytable].[field_a] as [a],
    [mytable].[field_b] as [b]
   FROM
    [mytable]
   FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
  ),
  ']'
 ) as [jsonResult]
```

It's working in my case, but I think it's a bit ugly.

Is there a way to improve this request to display the array brackets whether there are rows or not?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: thanks for your reply @YitzhakKhabinsky , i've added a table creation script for reproduction purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FOR JSON` operator does not return anything at all if there are no rows to serialize.

You can instead use `ISNULL` to return an empty array

```sql
SELECT ISNULL((
    SELECT
     t.field_a as a,
     t.field_b as b
    FROM
     mytable t
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
  ), '[]');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=52d09d2e541383d8cd75d6ad9d8c8f51)